# Combine and rekey multiple objects in jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm starting with a JSON file that has multiple objects

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "url": "https://zombo.com"
}
{
  "name": "bar",
  "url": "https://acme.com"
}
```

and I'm trying to combine those into a single object with the `name` attribute as the key:

```
{
  "widgets": {
    "foo": {
      "url": "https://zombo.com"
    },
    "bar": {
      "url": "https://acme.com"
    }
  }
}
```

I've been banging my head against this for a while and I think I'm fairly close with the following query:

```
{ widgets: (reduce . as $item ({}; . + {($item.name): {url: $item.url}})) }
```

However, this results in multiple objects and I'm running out of ideas.

jqplay available here: https://jqplay.org/s/SI7XEMb5l9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it like [this](https://jqplay.org/s/qlxyTJd3lv):

```
jq -s '{ widgets: map( { (.name): {url} } ) | add }'
```

- `-s` (`--slurp`) combines the objects to an array of objects
- `map( { (.name): { url } } )` reshapes each object
- `add` concatenates the array elements into a single object
- and finally, I build an object with `{ widgets: ... }`.

Comment: Very clean, and thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce` with `inputs`:

```
jq -n '{ widgets : (reduce inputs as $p ({}; . + ($p | { (.name) : { url } }))) }' file
```